# Estimate kanthal's temperature by power dissipation

Tags: power, resistors, temperature, heat

I've a bare Kanthal A-1 wire, And I want to Estimate it's temperature, basically to  make a °C vs W plot.

In this [post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/65200/is-it-possible-to-calculate-how-much-heat-dissipation-and-temperature-rise-will)

Thermal resistance is used to do it as:

```
Thermal_resistance = 200°C/W.              
power_dissipation = 400 mW   

T = 400 mW*200°C/W 
T = 80°C
```

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_conductivity)

> Thermal resistance = L/(kA), measured in K·W\$^{-1}\$ (equivalent to: °C/W)

But I can't find this parameter in the wire [specifications](http://kanthal.com/en/products/material-datasheets/strip/kanthal-a-1/)

But they do show a Thermal Conductivity table:

```
+----------------+-----------+          
| Temperature °C | W m-1 K-1 |          
+----------------+-----------+          
| 50             | 11        |        
+----------------+-----------+        
| 600            | 20        |         
+----------------+-----------+  
| 800            | 22        |           
+----------------+-----------+           
| 1000           | 26        |           
+----------------+-----------+
```

If I've a wire with:

```
l = 40cm          
d = 0.3mm             
P = 50W
```

How can I use the provided data to find the temperature?

Edit:

I made the measurements but the experimental results are quite off from the theoretical values, at least regarding to temperature. I somehow expect it because of the effect of the thermocouple touching the wire during the measurement   is quite evident

[image]

Resistance was calculated by measuring current and voltage, and temperature was measured  with a K-type thermocouple.

[image]

Comment: Simple answer: you can't. You would have to model the thermal conductivty from wire to air (or media) vs sourrounding T.

Comment: Why can't you simply measure temperature and wattage?

Comment: @uint128_t I've done that, is not that simple. I updated my answer with the results I got.